# should background validation disappear when i click on any pop-up?

Tags: content-management

In my web application, there is a search box.When I insert wrong data in search box and TAB out from that search box.
Then I try to open a popup. Background validation is remained same as it is.

So Is there any UX rules for background validation?

[image]

Comment: Does the pop-up show when you press the green bulk update button, or if you insert a query that doesn't give back any results in any of the input fields?

Comment: @Wanda  - Yes pop up open on clicking bulk update button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the action in the pop-up is not related with the validation, I think it shouldn't stay. In pop-up, you update a field, in the form on the page you submit some values for multiple fields, so the user should focus on the current action.

Answer (score 1):

### The validation should stay

If you remove the inline validation you will lead users into thinking that the problems had disappeared. Therefore, users will try to submit the form but the errors will appear again. That's an unnecessary interaction which could confuse users, increase their cognitive load, and take more time to fill up the forms. You want to avoid this because that's bad experience.

Update:
If after filling up the popup, the errors are fixed, then you should not display the inline validation.

Answer (score 0):

**Keep the validation, if it's still accurate.**

Inline validation has its charm because it gives positive (✓) - or negative (✕) - feedback right when its needed. However, this also means users will assume the problem has been resolved if the corresponding error message disappears. If this is not the case, you'll risk frustrating your user when the exact same error message pops up again later.

In the same vein, if an error has been resolved, remove the error message immediately. Don't leave it up to the user to figure out when their input has been considered acceptable.

> There’s a direct correlation between how and when users are presented
>   with form validation errors and the pace and effort with which they
>   are able resolve those errors (Baymard, 2016).
>   [Source](https://baymard.com/blog/inline-form-validation)